# Detect when app finishes loading after opening from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, sleep, background-process, exit

When my app is first opened there is a long loading time so I can display a loading screen. When the user exits the app by clicking the home button then re-opens it (the `viewDidLoad`/`viewDidAppear` methods aren't called again) the app has another loading period, I guess while it's "waking up".

What method can I use to detect the user hitting the home button to send the app into the background and what method can I use to detect that the app has been revived from the background?

This should be sufficient enough to provide my loading screen properly but just in-case. Is there also a method for detecting when the loading has finished after a "revival"?

Comment: [Do not use signatures, salutations or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a notification for `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`. There you can do your stuff.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Register for the notifcation 
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshView) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];  

}  

-(void)refreshView
{
/* 
 Invoked when application enters foreground. Do your stuff

 */   

 }
```

To remove observer

```
-(void)dealloc
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
  [super  dealloc];
}
```

Comment: This worked great for detecting when it finished loading.. do you have code to detect when the user clicks the home button so that I can display the loading screen?

Comment: ^I used `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` is this proper?

Comment: When  you want to perform? When app enters foreground or exit to background? You only need to show the app launch image at first time.

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Use `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` for entering the background.

Comment: It's not the app launch image, when the app enters the background and then re-enters to the foreground there is about a 6 second loading time where all buttons on the screen become in-active so I need to show a loading screen...

Comment: @Anil You need to remove the observer too. This is typically done in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: The code I just posted displays the loading screen when the app exits but the problem is if I just double tap the home button that code is triggered, also if I just double tap the home button to bring up the bottom navbar and then I click back onto the app view to go back to the app without ever exiting it your code is never called and the loading screen stays forever haha

Comment: Why do I remove the observer? And how?

Comment: @rmaddy just saw your post, testing it now!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw See the docs for `NSNotificationCenter`. There is an obvious method for doing that. You want to call it in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: Thankyou, I used `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` which I now see is edited into the code above... Do I ever have to call it back if it is removed or is this process automated?

Comment: No. You dont want to call it. System will handle it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if anyone knows... when the app is going to enter the background I begin animating my UIActivityIndicator and when the user clicks the app to open it again the ActivityIndicator is frozen... It's not that the code to animate it wasn't called it's just that when the app enters the foreground and is loading for a few seconds everything seems to freeze, including UIImageViews I had animating... once loading is done they all start animating again (including loading activity indicator) ... is there any way to force the ActivityIndicator to animate while the app is loading?

Answer (score 2):

Albert you can detect home button click on this two method declared in AppDelegate

```
 - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

and these are notification you can use

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(setFlag:)
                                             name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object: [UIApplication sharedApplication]];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(setFlag1:)
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: [UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, but going through the app-delegate is more of a hassle than the previous answer given.

Comment: Why are you using the same selector for both notifications? That's a bad idea since you need to handle each notification differently. Plus, the opposite of the "background" method/notification is the "foreground" method/notification, not the "resign active" ones.

Comment: Yes you can make use of mentioned notification in that case.

Comment: @maddy it is just an idea for using notification :)